# Bulk insert of utf-8 vs utf-16 encoded data

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, bulkinsert, utf-16

I have a table in my SQL Server that has the following columns

```
create table raw.sub_brand_channel_mapping 
(
    ImportFileId int NULL,
    [sub_brand_id] int ,
    [sub_brand_name] [nvarchar](1024) ,
    [channel_country_id] int ,
    [channel_id] int,
    [channel_name] [nvarchar](1024) ,
    [status] [varchar](1024) ,
    [eff_start_date] date ,
    [eff_end_date] date
)
```

I am trying to bulk insert a `.csv` file. My table has 9 columns, whereas my csv data file has 8 columns. The first column "ImportFileId" is supposed to be filled later. For this purpose, I am using a format file that looks like below.

```
10.0
8
1      SQLCHAR            0       1000       "|"     2    sub_brand_id                          ""
2      SQLCHAR            0       2000      "|"     3    sub_brand_name                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3      SQLCHAR            0       2000       "|"     4    channel_country_id                    ""
4      SQLCHAR            0       2000      "|"     5    channel_id                            ""
5      SQLCHAR            0       2000      "|"     6    channel_name                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6      SQLCHAR            0       2000       "|"     7    status                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7      SQLCHAR            0       2000        "|"       8     eff_start_date                         ""
8      SQLCHAR            0       2000        "\r\n"     9       eff_end_date                             ""
```

It can be seen that the first column is left empty. When I use BULK INSERT using the data as utf-8 encoding, my BULK INSERT is successful. However since SQL Server version 12 doesn't support utf-8 encoding, special characters in my data change.

To maintain the original data, I convert the encoding to utf-16. However, when I use the same BULK INSERT command with the same format file, I get an error:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (sub_brand_id).

My bulk insert query looks like this:

```
BULK INSERT <table> FROM <data_path>  
WITH (  
  FORMATFILE =   <Format_File_path>
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  LASTROW = 3
)
```

P.S. My data does have special characters, names in weird chinese and japanese languages, portuguese and spanish mix. To keep the data unadulterated, I need to use utf-16.

Can anyone provide a reason and a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of the head, several suggestions:

You can add `datafiletype = 'widechar'` into the `WITH` clause of the `bulk insert` statement. This might be tricky, however, since SQL Server behaviour might be different depending on whether the data file has the BOM or not. Would be better to test both cases.

If that doesn't help, I would try to change column definitions in the format file to `SQLNCHAR` (not sure about this, though).

Comment: I have tried out both the above suggestions. But it doesn't work for both of them !! 
P.S. - If my table has the same number of columns as that of my data file and I do BULK INSERT. then it works.